# Passing string to javascript with a PDO MySQL query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, string, pdo

I've got a table that has columns 'banned_ip' and 'reason', and I'm trying to display an error message specific to the banned user. For some reason, there seems to be a problem with displaying $row['reason']. Any ideas?

PHP:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM blackList WHERE banned_ip = :ip');
$stmt->execute(array('ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    echo "<script language='javascript'> displayBanError('" . $row['reason'] . "'); </script>";
}
```

JS:

```
function displayBanError(reason) {
    document.getElementById('error_field').innerHTML = "<p>Error: This IP has been blacklisted.<br>Reason: " + reason + "</p>";
}
```

Comment: Does the reason show in the HTML?  In the javascript tag?

Comment: My first guess is that the reason contains a `'` which needs to be escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing plain PHP with JavaScript may be a hell, because of all these quotes and other characters to be escaped. Try to pass PHP -> JS strings [base64-encoded in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php), in JS there are [functions to decode it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) back to readable form.

...or try [Smarty](http://smarty.net).